# Regex in Java: Finding the numbers that follow a given set of substrings

Tags: java, regex, substring

I have a number of strings that have a format loosely like this:

```
String blah =  "Blah bleh bluh Id. 24 bleh" ;

String bleh = "Foo Bar Foo Id 24" ;

String foo =  "Blah Foo Bleh Bar Tag.93 foo" ;

String bar ="Junk Jibberish Id.93" ;
```

Where I have some text, ultimately followed by some string that is in a set of possible identifiers (ID, Id, Identifier, Tag, etc.), followed then by either no spacing, a period and a space, just a period, or just a space, and then some number (1-4 digits) and possibly more text after that

I want to capture the substring in the format of "id93" or "tag93" or "id24" etc.

Kind of a specific question, I know, but I have no consistent single characters to separate the data I'm trying to capture.

What Regex pattern should I follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex pattern `\b(id|tag)\.?\s*(\d{1,4})\b` with case insensitivity modifier and join groups 1 &  2.

---

***Edit:*** Java regex format: `\\b(id|tag)\\.?\\s*(\\d{1,4})\\b`

Comment: Did you mean \\. instead of \. ?

Also, I'm getting these errors...


illegal escape character: Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\b(id|tag)\\.?\s*(\d{1,4})\b");

on \d and \b

Using Java 1.6

Comment: @user1558822 - In Java you have to escape **each** \ character with another \, so go with `\\b(id|tag)\\.?\\s*(\\d{1,4})\\b`

Comment: Also my editor is giving me this error:

Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Why would this be?